# Execute and get value of dynimically created Sql query in Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

How to execute and get value from dynamically created SQL in loop with stored procedure.

With the dynamic query, I have extracting 'table' and 'column' name from other query result:

I have tried like below:

```
  @val1 VARCHAR(100),
  @CODE VARCHAR(100)   

DECLARE @dyntbl varchar(100);
DECLARE @Codename varchar(100); 
DECLARE @Relationtext varchar(100);
DECLARE @_SQL nvarchar(max);

DECLARE @i int = 0
DECLARE @count int = 0;
DECLARE @isexist varchar(10);
DECLARE @rowcount int = 0;

SELECT @count = COUNT(*) FROM Table1 WHERE TABLENAME = @val1

        WHILE (@i < @count)
        BEGIN
            SELECT @dyntbl = DYNTBL, @grp = GRP FROM
            (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS RowNumber,*
                FROM Table1 WHERE  TABLENAME = @val1) AS TBL1 WHERE RowNumber = (@i +1);

            --First Check if Table Exist or not
            IF (EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].['+@dyntbl +']') AND type in (N'U')))
            BEGIN

                SET @_SQL = 'SELECT COUNT(*) from [' + @dyntbl + '] where ['+ @grp+']='''+ @CODE + '''
                EXECUTE sp_executesql @isexist= @_SQL
// How to get Count of each query 
// Control does not come to this point                  
print @isexist // This doesn't get any value
                IF(@isexist = 0)
                BEGIN
                    --print 'do something'
                END
            END

            SET @i = @i + 1

            END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use a variable that you define in your procedure, populate in your dynamic query, and reference as an output parameter in your use on sp_executesql, would look something like this:

```
declare @cnt int,
        @sqlparams nvarchar(max) = N'@cnt int output';

set @_SQL = 'select @cnt = count(*) from [' + @dyntbl + '] where ['+ @grp+']='''+ @CODE + '''

exec sp_executesql @_SQL, @sqlparams, @cnt output;

-- Now the local @cnt variable will hold the results of the dynamic query executed via sp_executesql
select @cnt;
```

For reference, [see here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx).